# Marker in google maps for android

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to know how i can set "**OnClick**" for a **marker** on **google maps** in android.

*Example: User touch the marker and My app detect this.*

My marker

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(-18.142, 178.431), 2));
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mUiSettings = map.getUiSettings();

        mUiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Sydney")
                .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
                .position(sydney));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `OnMarkerClickListener`, like following:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                // do your stuff
                return true;
            }});
```

Comment: also return true I think after you have 'done stuff'

Answer (score 0):

```
implement OnMarkerClickListener

public class MarkerDemoActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
        implements OnMarkerClickListener
    {
        private Marker myMarker;    

            myMarker = googleMap.addMarker();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

            if (marker.equals(myMarker)) 
            {
                //handle click here
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
this.googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {                       
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                                Log.d(TAG, arg0.getTitle() + " | " + arg0.getPosition().toString());            
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
```